# How to limit the lookup by Type?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup

I added 2 RecordType values to the Account object.  Now when an Account lookup is invoked from a visual force page, I would like to limit it by RecordType.

Is there a way to do this?  Hopefully via apex tags?
Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Account search settings, you can include Record Type as a field to filter on in the lookup dialog. Or you can limit the records available by using lookup filters. (The latter is configured at the bottom of the screen of the lookup field in setup.)